# put map into value of other map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, put

I want to put a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` into value of `Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Integer>>>`.

```
try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)));
            String currentLine;
            int numLine=0;
            while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                numLine++;
                Collection<String> wordsInOneLigne = Arrays.asList(currentLine.split(" "));
                List<String> distinctWordsInOneLigne = wordsInOneLigne.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
                for (String word :  distinctWordsInOneLigne) {
                    if(!word.isEmpty()){
                        List<Integer> linePositionsOfWord = new LinkedList<>();
                        if(currentLine.contains(word)){
                            linePositionsOfWord.add(numLine);
                            map.clear();
                            map.put(filePath,linePositionsOfWord);
                            map1.put(word, map);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        }
```

distinctWordsInOneLine is a list that contains words in line.

Got output: `{word1={D:\Files\file1.txt=[3]}, word3={D:\Files\file1.txt=[3]}, word2={D:\Files\file1.txt=[3]}}`

Expected output: `{word1={D:\Files\file1.txt=[numberoflinecontainsword]}, word3={D:\Files\file1.txt=[numberoflinecontainsword]}, word2={D:\Files\file1.txt=[numberoflinecontainsword]}}`

I need help please :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to do here but `map.clear()` is very suspicious - all the time it is the same object, in every iteration of the loop. So if you clear it in 10th iteration, the object in all the previous iterations will be cleared as well. Perhaps you should create a new map in each iteration of the while loop or something like that.

Comment: I tried to clear map each time. Even when i delete this line nothing change

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String word : distinctWordsInOneLigne) {
                        Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
                        if (!word.isEmpty()) {
                            List<Integer> linePositionsOfWord = new LinkedList<>();
                            if (currentLine.contains(word)) {
                                linePositionsOfWord.add(numLine);
                                if (mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder.containsKey(word)) {
                                    Map<String, List<Integer>> mapList = mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder.get(word);
                                    if (mapList.containsKey(filePath)) {
                                        List<Integer> list = mapList.get(filePath);
                                        list.add(numLine);
                                    } else {
                                        mapList.put(filePath, linePositionsOfWord);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    map.put(filePath, linePositionsOfWord);
                                    mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder.put(word, map);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

This work good for me! now I want change optimase it by using `computeIfAbsent` and `computeIfPresent`.